# Смена inline menu по нажатию на кнопку (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram, inline

Хочу сделать так, что бы при нажатии на `Inline` кнопку мне выводилось следующее `Inline` меню в том же сообщении.

У меня вот такой вот код:

*#bot.py*

```
@dp.message_handler(text=['Магазин'])
async def shop(message: types.Message):
    await  message.answer("Выберите подраздел: ", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full2)
```

*#keyboards.py*

```
inline_btn_3 = InlineKeyboardButton('A', callback_data='A')
inline_btn_4 = InlineKeyboardButton('B', callback_data='B')
inline_btn_5 = InlineKeyboardButton('C', callback_data='C')
inline_kb_full2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(inline_btn_3,inline_btn_4,inline_btn_5)
```

**Надо что бы при нажатии на "A" у меня появлялось следующее меню:**

#keyboards.py

```
inline_btn_6 = InlineKeyboardButton('1', switch_inline_query_current_chat='')
inline_btn_7 = InlineKeyboardButton('2', switch_inline_query_current_chat='')
inline_btn_8 = InlineKeyboardButton('3', switch_inline_query_current_chat='')
inline_btn_9 = InlineKeyboardButton('Назад ↩️',callback_data='Back')
inline_kb_full3 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(inline_btn_6,inline_btn_7,inline_btn_8,inline_btn_9)
```

Что мне дописать в bot.py, что бы при нажатии одной кнопки в меню у меня появлялось уже другое меню **под тем же сообщением**?

Answer (score 0):

для того, чтобы это сделать вам нужно поймать callback_data из первой клавиатуры.

```py
@dispatcher.callback_query_handler(lambda call: "<CALLBACK>" in call.data)
async def next_keyboard(call):

    await call.message.edit_reply_markup(<YOUR KEYBOARD>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поймать колбэк первой клавиатуры и далее написать изменение сообщения

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda callback: callback.data in [A, B, C])
async daf next_keybord(callback: types.Callback_query):
    await callback.edit_message(reply_markup= <new keybord>)
```